# What should be the relative path of the csv file need

Tags: java, csv, relative-path

I want to create an executable java program which will read a csv file at the same location  as the executable file. What should be the relative path of the csv file in the code. Im using eclipse. Will the same path will work for both windows n  Mac ?

Comment: Paths should be (and are, AFAIK) platform independent, especially when the file is located in the same folder as the executable/code file.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourfile.csv")
```

Using this approach you don't need to specify a relative path for a file at the same level as your class. This will work on all platforms.

Comment: Then the .csv is packed inside the .jar (read-only); the ideal solution. Should the csv need to be written to, you still can use that resource csv as _template_ to construct some csv file in the user's home directory: `System.getProperty("user.home")` - so several users have their own modified data.

Comment: But that does not seem to be the requirement of the question?

Comment: right; just wanted to anticipate the wish to update those data, because even then (keeping the original file in the jar) makes sense.